# Timestamp field into oracle by using sqlloader

Tags: oracle, timestamp, sql-loader

I am trying to load this source row into oracle

Source row:

1000-01-01 00:00:00:000000

by using this CTL statement;

entrydate   TIMESTAMP   "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss:ff6"

but I am getting

ORA-26041: DATETIME/INTERVAL datatype conversion error

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp format or data problem  `hh` - Hour of day (1-12). `hh24` - Hour of day (0-23).

`TIMESTAMP "YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss:ff6"` try this version.